# VS Regex to "Find All" ignoring spaces and new lines

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio "Find and Replace" window to search for the following pattern using Regex: `INNER JOIN T2` while ignoring any spaces or new lines. [Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28inner%29%28%3f%28%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%29%5cs%29.*%28join%29%28%3f%28%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%29%5cs%29.*%28T2%29&i=SELECT+*+FROM+T1+INNER++++join%0d%0a+++T2+ON...&o=is) is .NET tester that actually works as expected. However, the reason it works is because I checked the "**Singleline**" checkbox found on the right side.

In Visual Studio this Regex doesn't work and only matches results on the same line. How can I replicate what the "Singleline" check box does?

Here is the Regex pattern linked above:

```
(inner)(?([^\r\n])\s).*(join)(?([^\r\n])\s).*(T2)
```

And here is the input that only works when the Singleline checkbox is checked, while Visual Studio doesn't have such checkbox.

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER    join
   T2 ON...
```

**EDIT**

To give context to the question (if not already figured out), the purpose is to replace those `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because of structural changes made to the `T1` and `T2` tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should match:

```
inner(\r\n)*\s+join(\r\n)*\s+T2
```

The replacement expression could be `LEFT OUTER JOIN T2`

Explanation:

- `inner` - match text 'inner'
- `(\r\n)*\s+` - match any number of line breaks (including none) and at least one space
- `join` - match text 'join'
- `(\r\n)*\s+` - match any number of line breaks (including none) and at least one space
- `T2` - match text 'T2'

Edit: as pointed out in the comments this simpler and elegant regex does the same:

```
inner[\s\r]+join[\s\r]+T2
```

Example:

Find:

[image]

After replace:

[image]

Comment: The VS regex docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio)

Comment: If `inner(\r\n)*\s+join(\r\n)*\s+T2` works, `inner[\s\r]+join[\s\r]+T2` is enough.